# Region mask in the center - Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the script below I create a mask based on coordinates and plot them in the original position and also starting at position 0,0. How can I plot another region mask (mask1venter) center?

Code:

```
xCoord = [354 500 100 363];
yCoord = [309 500 600 360];

if max(xCoord)>max(yCoord)
     matrixLength = max(xCoord);
 else
     matrixLength = max(yCoord);
end

xCoordMin = xCoord-min(xCoord);
yCoordMin = yCoord-min(yCoord);

xCoordCenter = xCoord-round((max(xCoord))/2);
yCoordCenter = yCoord-round((max(yCoord))/2);

mask1 = poly2mask(yCoord,xCoord,matrixLength,matrixLength);
mask1Min = poly2mask(yCoordMin,xCoordMin,matrixLength,matrixLength);
mask1Center = poly2mask(yCoordCenter,xCoordCenter,matrixLength,matrixLength);

imshowpair(mask1,mask1Min)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use subplot, add the two masks or logical OR the two masks

**Subplot**

```
figure
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(mask1)
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(mask1Min)
subplot(2,2,3)
imshow(mask1Center)
```

[image: subplot result]

**Add the two image**

```
figure
imshowpair(mask1,mask1Min + mask1Center)
```

[image: add result]

**Logical OR the two masks**

```
figure
imshowpair(mask1,mask1Min | mask1Center)
```

[image: logical OR result]

Comment: How can I fit the shape in the middle of the image?